# How to connectt Skype for Business Online data from Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business

I am trying to start collecting Skype for Business Online data using Microsoft Graph Explorer in order to do my own reporting. Eventually, my goal is to automate this process using API calls and write the return data in my own monitoring database.

I opened a O365 trial account and using graph explorer with my global admin account to generate some SfB reports but having no luck:
[SfB Business Activity Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzvE9.png)

Am I doing something wrong here?

Also, I believe this query is supposed to return a CSV file. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The API you're using is in beta, and (contrary to [the published documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getskypeforbusinessactivityuserdetail)) seems to only work when:

- you provide an output format parameter
- that output format is JSON

The call you're trying to make will work as follows: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getSkypeForBusinessActivityUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json`

You're not the only one waiting for these APIs to solidify and include more information. Hope this helps!